# Understanding Gemfile (Rails): "require mongo" unnecessary if "gem 'mongo'" is already included?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, rubygems, gemfile

This is our Gemfile.

Is the line **require mongo** redundant since **gem 'mongo'** is already included?

If not, what is the purpose of **require mongo**?

We're on Rails 3.

Thanks!

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

require 'rubygems'
require 'mongo'

gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'mongo'
gem 'mongo_mapper'
gem 'fastercsv'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'whois'
```

Comment: I don't know why you're need a `require 'mongo'` here. Couldn't you just remove it and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't put `require` statements in your Gemfile. This is also true for the `require 'rubygems'` on the line before.

What require does, is what it always does: load the gem. The Gemfile is loaded when you run `bundle install`. If you try to load a gem before `bundle install` has run, the gem might not be installed yet.

Gems specified in your Gemfile are required by Rails by default too, by the way.